# What is the difference between jQuery, Prototype, Extjs, mootools, Scriptaculous, Spry, YUI, DOJO framework?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frameworks, yui

I keep hearing about many JavaScript frameworks i.e.

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/)
[YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/)
[DOJO](http://www.dojotoolkit.org)
[ExtJs](http://www.sencha.com/)
[Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/)
[Mootools](http://mootools.net/)
[Scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/)
[Spry](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/spry/)

and a few more.

Can anyone please tell me what specific purpose, do these framework serve?

I am a user of jQuery only.

Comment: If you follow the links that *you* provided (ExtJS one is wrong, by the way) I think most of the frameworks' homepages tell you what they're for...

Comment: @str_repeat('n', 6) ------ Every framework states that it is for DOM, AJAX ------ but I was asking about USP

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a short description, based on my experience and knowledge (and IMO):

**jQuery** -> is the most popular javascript library available (great support available on the net and a lot of plugin written for it), it's simple for all (included designers). It's the best choice for dom manipulation and to write code quickly (ideal for front-end)

**DOJO** -> advanced js library which offers mechanism for loading js "modules" as necessary

**ExtJs** -> one of the most advanced and powerful js library. It's build with OOP in mind, it offers an huge number of UI components. It's not intended for designers, it's pretty heavy (size of sources). It's the ideal choice for advanced backoffice UI

**Prototype** -> the evil! Simply avoid this library, it extends default js objects by causing a lot of troubles

**YUI** -> similar to ExtJS (ExtJs was born as an extension of YUI, so if you have to choose one of the two go for ext :P)
Mootools -> I don't know :P

**Scriptaculous** -> as far I know, the best for js animations (it was one of the firs library for this task)

**Spry** -> it introduces some new "concepts" such dataSet. Few people use it :(

Comment: +1 - excellent, to the point, concise answer.

Comment: Just for anyone else who lands here: 

jQuery is for lightweight scripting. AKa front end websites, and simple stuff. Can be use for other, but optimised for manipulating content that is already created.

ExtJs is ALSO intended for designers. Xero is a great example. Anyone can use SASS to theme ExtJS.

ExtJS is intended for applications and is the most popular framework for larger applications due to it's MVC structure and it's enterprise level data packages. (drag and drop IDE's and eclipse plugins)

Answer (score 2):

These all are [javascript libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_library), more or less they share the common purpose albeit with different syntax:

- Cross-browser issues handling
- Animation
- Custom dialogs and widgets
- Ability to write lesser code
- Specific selector engine
- Creation/Modification of DOM
- Event Handling
- Utility Functions
- AJAX

Following article is also interesting to read:

- [Compare JavaScript frameworks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-jsframeworks/)

Comment: Thx Sarfaraz ---- having a look at the link

Answer (score 1):

Given they are all JS frameworks they serve almost the same purpose as jQuery serves, by they differ in things such as ease of use, feature richness, UI components, shielding from browser specific functionality, performance, and many others.